# How i return complete file path in which start with Ex: TC00 in java

Tags: java, selenium

Please refer to the below attached image given image is my problem statement.

I write the code but not showing correct output it print object value and i want file path value

ex:in particular folder 3 file and name start with tc001 ,tc002,tc003 
if I write tc00 I want to search complete file list start with name tc00.

[image]

```
 private static String GetFilePathWhereFilenameStartsWith(String StartingWord,String SourceFolderPath)
{
    System.out.println("** GetFilePathWhereFilenameStartsWith **"+"\n");
    String Filepath = null;
    File root = new File(SourceFolderPath);
    FilenameFilter beginwithnm = new FilenameFilter()
    {
    public boolean accept(File directory, String filename)
        {
            return filename.startsWith(StartingWord);
        }
    };

    File[] files = root.listFiles(beginwithnm);
    Filepath=files.toString();      
    return Filepath;    
}
```

For calling function I write this code

```
String filepath = GetFilePathWhereFileNameStartsWith("TC10", "C:\\Users\\Reshma\\Desktop\\FRAMEWORK_COMPONENTS\\TC1001.CreateCompanySUMMMARY.xml");
System.out.println("FilepathIs :" +filepath);
```

Current Output is showing This  :=  [Ljava.io.File;@8c4f57

Any one know how I to solve this type of problem or any alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling toString () on an array. You either want to return that array rather than a string if it acceptable to find multiple files or take the first file from the array and use something like [File#getAbsolutePath ()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()).

```
return files.length > 0 ? files[0].getAbsolutePath() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing the Filepath object and not a String:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePaths=GetFilePathWhereFilenameStartsWith("TC", "G:\\NetBeansProjects\\Vaje");
    System.out.println(filePaths);
}
private static String GetFilePathWhereFilenameStartsWith(final String sw,String source){
    String output="";
    File f=new File(source);
    File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith(sw);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < matchingFiles.length; i++) {
        output+=matchingFiles[i]+"\n";
    }
    return output;
```

}

Comment: This returns a long string of all matching files separated by "\n". This is not what the question is asking for.